# How do I set a key to open html file in browser in vscode without any extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I know there are few extensions available in vscode to open html files in browser. But I don't want to use any of them. I'd love to learn how to set a key, say "F12" to open html files in default browser.

For example with this key binding code below, we can do the exact same in Sublime text

`{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "open_in_browser"}`

Btw, I've tried this but it asks for questions every time instead of opening the .html in browser directly. - https://gist.github.com/borekb/269391102b75c4196a811dd805336dd5#file-tasks-json

Does anyone know how I can set the key **F12** in **vscode** to open .html files in browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The given example (copied from the page you provided) is wrong.

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "Chrome Canary",
  "windows": {
    "command": "C:\\Users\\borek\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe"
  },
  "args": ["${file}"]
}
```

You should replace the top level `"command"` with `"label"`. Not only that, but each task must be part of the `"tasks"` array. Thus the whole thing becomes as follows:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Chrome Canary",
      "windows": {
        "command": "C:\\Users\\borek\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe"
      },
      "args": ["${file}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

After that you can add the following to your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+shift+c",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "Chrome Canary"
}
```

You can open the `tasks.json` in VSCode and edit it right there - VSCode will give you suggestions.